# creating an efficient query with a UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get a list of all citizens of a country and list them in a table with 3 rows.
The last row shows 'YES' or 'NO' depending on whether or not the person was born in a certain city.

What I did was create two queries: The first query gets all the citizens who were born in the city, and the second query gets all the citizens not born in the city.

Then I just do a UNION.

THe query runs and I think the results look good.

But I was wondering, is this the best way to form a query like this?

Thanks

```
--all citizens who were born in CityID = 5 who is in the USA
SELECT DISTINCT(CountryCitizenID), Country, 'YES' As Resident
FROM DT_Country_CitizenS dtu
INNER JOIN FT_City fte ON dtu.CountryCitizenID = fte.CitizenID
WHERE cityID = 5
AND Country = 'USA'

UNION

--all Citizens who were not born in CityID = 5 who is in the USA
SELECT  DISTINCT(CountryCitizenID), Country, 'NO' As Resident  
FROM DT_Country_CitizenS dtu 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT CitizenID 
    FROM FT_City fte 
    WHERE  dtu.CountryCitizenID = fte.CitizenID
    AND   cityID = 5)
AND Country = 'USA'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't need a `UNION` for this (and generally, when you have two queries that can't possibly intersect, you should use `UNION ALL` which avoids a unique sort (or similar operation)). Also, `DISTINCT` cannot apply to a single column, as your current query seems to imply. I find it unlikely that there are duplicates in the `CountryCitizenID` column, unless it is really poorly named, so I don't think `DISTINCT` is needed at all. Finally, what is the point of pulling the `Country` column at all, since by definition it will be the same in every row? I've changed it to a constant instead of pulling the actual value (this might prevent a lookup or give a better chance at using a skinnier index), but you shouldn't need that column in the output at all - the application should know that, since the `WHERE` clause filters to only rows where `Country = 'USA'`, there is no other value possible.

```
SELECT CountryCitizenID, Country = 'USA', Resident = CASE WHEN EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.FT_City fte 
    WHERE fte.CitizenID = dtu.CountryCitizenID
    AND   fte.cityID = 5
) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
FROM dbo.DT_Country_CitizenS AS dtu
WHERE dtu.Country = 'USA';
```

Comment: +1: Perfect approach without using `JOIN` or `UNION`.

Comment: @AaronBertran, congrats on reaching 100k!

Comment: thanks, I tried this, but my version of SQL Server doesn't like the 'AS' keyword. It gives me: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CountryCitizenID), 
       Country, 
       case when fte.CitizenID is not null then 'YES' else 'NO' As Resident
  FROM DT_Country_CitizenS dtu
    LEFT JOIN (select * 
                 from FT_City 
                where cityID = 5) fte 
         ON (dtu.CountryCitizenID = fte.CitizenID)
 WHERE Country = 'USA'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CountryCitizenID, Country, CASE WHEN fte.cityID IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END  As Resident
FROM DT_Country_CitizenS dtu
LEFT JOIN FT_City fte 
  ON dtu.CountryCitizenID = fte.CitizenID
  AND fte.cityID = 5
WHERE Country = 'USA'
```